# Overriding the highlighting of default highlight groups within a syntax file

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

In my custom syntax file, I have the following:

```
highlight default link sv_block_comment Comment
highlight default link sv_macro PreProc
...
```

I wanted to override the display of `PreProc` within the syntax file itself. I tried this:

```
highlight PreProc cterm=bold ctermfg=134
```

Then, when I first start-up a `.sv` file, the highlighting override doesn't take effect. Only after I do `:e` or `:vsplit <some other file>` does it take effect. Why does this happen? I thought that Vim reads my custom syntax file last thus my highlighting commands should override any prvious ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to override the display of `PreProc` within the syntax file itself.

Don't do that.

Syntax highlighting is handled by two complementary mechanisms:

- the syntax script defines custom groups and link them to default groups,
- the colorscheme defines the visual attributes of default highlight group and, if needed custom ones.

Mixing the two mechanisms is not a very good idea, if only because your visual attributes won't survive a colorscheme switch. Defining the visual attributes of a given group must be done at the colorscheme level. You basically have two options:

1. edit the colorscheme file,
2. override that specific group for all colorschemes or a specific one.

The reasoning behind the second method is described [here](https://github.com/vim/colorschemes/wiki/How-to-override-a-colorscheme%3F) but it should look like this:

```
augroup mycolors
autocmd!
autocmd ColorScheme * highlight PreProc cterm=bold ctermfg=134
augroup END
```